# Bootstrap 5.1 - Responsive row/col - Going from "col-12" to "col-md"

Tags: css

I have this:

```
<div class="col"></div>
```

For mobile I have this:

```
<div class="col-4"></div>
```

**I want to join them together, but it doesn't work as expected:**

```
<div class="col-4 col-md"></div>
```

Basically the "md" has to be flexible "col", but I don't know how to reset that previous "col-4".

Comment: Just specify the responsive class for all devices. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

Comment: @Vishnudev You can't specify for "xs" separately

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just added this to every class:

```
.col-md {
     flex: 1 0 0%;
     width:auto; /*fix width*/
}
```

Comment: This corresponds to `col-auto`. Note that you have to specify a media query to keep the logic, Adding a media width >= 768px, you will just redefine `col-md-auto`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure they are in rows? Because in this case it works normally.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md col-4">
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, ad!
    </div>
    <div class="col-md col-4">
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, ad!
    </div>
    <div class="col-md col-4">
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, ad!
    </div>
    <div class="col-md col-4">
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, ad!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your needs, you just have to specify `col-md-auto` instead of `col-md`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 col-md-auto">
      AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-md-auto">
      BBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBB
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-md-auto">
      CCCCC CCCCC CCCCC CCCCC CCCCC CCCCC CCCCC CCCCC CCCCC CCCCC CCCCC CCCCC CCCCC CCCCC CCCCC
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately "col-md-auto" isn't same as "col"

Comment: both classes apply `flex: 0 0 auto;` and `width: auto;` so it's supposed to be the same

Comment: but it's not... I tested.... you have 3 same col-4 and same content... you should do differnet contents and different rows and then try "col-2 col" and then try "col-2 col-auto" ... and it will be fkd.. because col sets a width, that col auto doesn't cancel

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  then ?

Comment: unfortunately i dont have time for this bs

Comment: I feel like people put more effort to answer than you to ask then